# intercept xmlhttprequest android Webview

Tags: java, android, ajax, webview, xmlhttprequest

so I have an Embed URL of a (Jwplayer) video
want to extract the HLS stream Url (.m3u8) of the video from my android application.

jsoup is not an option because the webpage source code is obfuscated somehow and I can't get it to work

so I sniffed the requests made by the webpage when its loading and I can find some requests sent to the wanted (.m3u8)HLS URL.

what I did is create a hidden Webview and i loaded the embed URL in it and try to intercept the requests, therfore extract the link and pass it to EXoplayer2 to play the video.

the problem is that the requests made to that URL are Xmlhttprequest and the method `shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)` of the `Webviewclient` can't intercept those type of calls or requests.

therefore I need a way to intercept those requests so i can extract the stream URL.

Comment: So you are sniffing a `URL`, .. is that correct?  I didn't get how you did that.  What about playing the **video** on the original player?

Comment: look its an embed URL of a video.
normally ill find the stream URL in the source code of the webpage in the <script> tag of JWplayer but in this case the webpage source code is obfuscated so i need to improvise to get the LINK.
when the page is loading it making requests to a streaming server to play that video 
on JWplayer to get that link i am trying to intercept the request and test the URL if it contains .m3u8 then pass it to exoplayer.

Comment: when the page loads its making ajax calls wich i need to intercept from my webview in android so from the bottom i need a way to intercept xmlhttprequests in a webview . its pretty self explanatory.

Comment: take this URL as an example [link](https://www.faselhd.live/video_player?nv2=true&uid=0&vid=f3b85125dd05c2bff162863174931a7c)

Comment: No, no, no... Japanese baby cartoons, not for me...  Cannot even watch it...  You know, I don't get it - why the government is pushing that on SO now...

Comment: are u willing to help or not ?